# How to get the patch of every changed file of a single commit?

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I’m trying to get some information about the commit-history by mining a git-repository. I’m using the package libgit2sharp.

So far, I got the commit-author, committer, sha-value, commit-date and the commit-message. My problem is to move through the repository-tree, to get the patch of all changed files of every single commit.

Does anybody solve this problem before, or can help me?

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"path\to\.git"))
            {
                var commits = repo.Commits; 
                Commit lastCommit = commits.Last();

                foreach (Commit commit in commits)
                    if (commit.Sha != lastCommit.Sha)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(commit.Sha);
                        Console.WriteLine(commit.Author.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(commit.Committer.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(commit.Author.When); //Commit-Date
                        Console.WriteLine(commit.Message);

                        Tree tree = commit.Tree;
                        Tree parentCommitTree = lastCommit.Tree; 

                        TreeChanges changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parentCommitTree, tree);
                        foreach (TreeEntryChanges treeEntryChanges in changes)
                        {
                            ObjectId oldcontenthash = treeEntryChanges.OldOid;
                            ObjectId newcontenthash = treeEntryChanges.Oid;
                        } 
                     }   
            }
```

Another trying is the following code. It shows the files and folder of the root-level, but I cant open a folder.

```
foreach(TreeEntry treeEntry in tree)
   {
    // Blob blob1 = (Blob)treeEntry.Target;

    var targettype = treeEntry.TargetType;
    if (targettype == TreeEntryTargetType.Blob)
      {
        string filename = treeEntry.Name;
        string path = treeEntry.Path;
        string sha = treeEntry.Target.Sha;

        var filemode = treeEntry.Mode;
        Console.WriteLine(filename);
        Console.WriteLine(path);
      }
      else if (targettype == TreeEntryTargetType.Tree)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Folder: " + treeEntry.Name);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**>(How) to get the patch of all changed files of every single commit?**

Use the `Diff.Compare<Patch>()` method by passing it the `Tree` of each `Commit` you're willing to compare.

```
Tree commitTree1 = repo.Lookup<Commit>("f8d44d7").Tree;
Tree commitTree2 = repo.Lookup<Commit>("7252fe2").Tree;

var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(commitTree1, commitTree2);
```

One can find more usage details by taking a look at the test metthod **[CanCompareTwoVersionsOfAFileWithADiffOfTwoHunks()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs#L860-L895)** in the **DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs** test suite.

**>Another trying is the following code. It shows the files and folder of the root-level, but I cant open a folder.**

Each `TreeEntry` exposes a `Target` property returning the pointed at `GitObject`.

When the `TargetType` is of type `TreeEntryTargetType.Tree`, in order to retrieve this child `Tree`, you'd have to use the following:

```
var subTree = (Tree)treeEntry.Target;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer!

Now I receive the patch between two commits. With the following code, the OutOfMemoryException is often thrown.

```
LibGit2Sharp.Commit lastCommit = commits.First();
repository.CommitCount = commits.Count();
 foreach (LibGit2Sharp.Commit commit in commits) 
    if (commit.Sha != lastCommit.Sha)
      {
       Tree commitTree1 = repo.Lookup<LibGit2Sharp.Commit>(lastCommit.Sha).Tree;
       Tree commitTree2 = repo.Lookup<LibGit2Sharp.Commit>(commit.Sha).Tree;
       var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(commitTree1, commitTree2);
       // some value assigments                        
        lastCommit = commit;
  }
```

Comment: The exception isn't supposed to happen. Could you please submit a complete repro case to the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)**?

Comment: This is the full code. It happens at ca. 7.000 Commits

Comment: Please submit a dedicated issue in the tracker along with the url of the public repository you're working against

Comment: For reference, the logged issue is **[#790](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/790)**